# cannot find module in server.js

Tags: reactjs, require

I get the error **"Error: Cannot find module './todo.model'"**

schema is in the same folder 
here is the folder content :
- backend
  - data:db
  - node_modules
  - todo.model.js
  - package.json
  - server.js

this is the **server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;
**var Todo = require('./todo.model');**
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})
```

this is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let Todo = new Schema({
    todo_description: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_responsible: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_priority: {
        type: String
    },
    todo_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm *assuming* `require` is getting confused about the file extension, thinking the file is actually a `.model` extension.

Try being more explicit and include `.js`

```
require('./todo.model.js');
```